# Set property for each item in collection

Tags: c#, .net, foreach, ienumerable

I have an IEnumerable and I try to call "Text" setter in each item of the enumerable.
I can do:

```
foreach (Data d in DataEnumerable)
{
    d.Text="123";
}
```

I can also do:

```
DataEnumerable.All(x =>
    {
        x.Text = "123";
        return true;
    });
```

What is the best practice to call set method for each item of enumerable?

Comment: What do you mean by `best practice`? Most efficient? Most readable/maintainable? Also, consider [codereview.se] for questions about improving already-working code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first method is better.

The second is an *abuse* of [`Enumerable.All`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541.aspx). This method is intended to be used to test all elements of an Enumerable to see if they satisfy a condition. You are not doing that here.

There is a method `List.ForEach` which can be used for this sort of update operation, but the LINQ team decided *not* to add a corresponding method in `Enumerable`. See Eric Lippert's blog for details on *why* this decision was made:

- ["foreach" vs "ForEach"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx)